# Usage of QPen which is cosmetic but not width zero

Tags: qt, qpen

I have recently migrated an application from Qt 4 to Qt 5.  I used to use a default `QPen()` with width zero which was therefore cosmetic.  After migration I couldn't leave it as default (the default pen has changed to be of width 1 and therefore not cosmetic).  So I simply added a call to `setCosmetic(True)` so my pens were cosmetic but width 1.

However, this led to some unexpected (to me) behaviour.  In particular I had some `QGraphicsEllipseItem` objects which were giving incorrect selection behaviour: specifically, a very small ellipse, scaled up to a large size, would have a much larger `shape()` than it was being drawn.  It was being drawn with a cosmetic (1 pixel) pen but the shape was calculated as if the pen was of size 1 scaled up.

This is easily fixed: I simply set the `QPen` width to 0.  But it raised a question in my mind.

What is the intended semantics of a cosmetic pen with non-zero width?  Is this behaviour of the `QGraphicsEllipseItem` intended, and with useful application, or is it unexpected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for [`QGraphicsItem::paint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#paint):

> QGraphicsItem does not support use of cosmetic pens with a non-zero width.

Comment: Ahh interesting - thanks.  I wonder why the QPen allows them.